# System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: 'Set connectionId threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

After adding the line this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(); as follows

- public JScriptWindow()
             {
                 InitializeComponent();
                   this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();
                 CreateTab();
             }

  am getting inner Exception as follows..

[But when I remove this line(this.DataContext = new MainViewModel();) from the code the application runs fine. ]

[A]Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager cannot be cast to [B]Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager. Type A originates from 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' in the context 'LoadFrom' at location 'C:\Copy\Project\Aria Developement\AERAria\ARIA\ARIA.Main\bin\Release\Ascent\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll'. Type B originates from 'Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=3e4669d2f30244f4' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Copy\Project\Aria Developement\AERAria\ARIA\ARIA.Main\bin\Release\Libraries\Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.dll'.

When I continue the application with this exception finally it will through exception as shown in the link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QhFFd.jpg)